# call one Ant task after another

Tags: ant

I want to call sendmail once RunTests is complete, but its not working

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce" default="RunTests">
    <!--******************************************* P R O P E R T Y   F I L E *********************************************-->
    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>
    <!--*******************************************RunTests***********************************************************-->
    <target name="RunTests">
        <record name="RunTest.log" action="start"/>
            <sf:compileAndTest  username="${sf.backup_username}" password="${sf.backup_password}" serverurl="${sf.backup_serverurl}" >
                <runTests Alltests="true"/>
            </sf:compileAndTest>
        <record name="RunTest.log" action="stop"/>    
    </target>
    <target name="sendmail" depends="RunTests"> 
        <mail mailhost="email.corp.testcompany.com" mailport="25" subject="Run all tests - Sandbox 1337" messagefile="RunTest.log">
            <from address="user2@testcompany.com"/>
            <replyto address="user2@testcompany.com"/>
            <to address="user2@testcompany.com"/>
        </mail> 
    </target>       
</project>
```

I get following failures -

BUILD FAILED
C:\ANT_HOME\QA_1337_TestRunner\build.xml:8: Failed:

is there any way I can execute "sendemails" task even if there is failure for earlier task.

Answer (score 3):

try to run

```
ant sendmail
```

or change the default to sendmail

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce" default="sendmail">
```

and simply execute

```
ant
```

**EDIT:**

After a quick look at [salesforce doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest.htm) for the task `sf:compileAndTest`, I didn't find any useful information on how avoid target execution failure whenever the tests and/or compilation fail. (maybe the [`checkonly`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest_request.htm) property, but I'm not sure this is what you need nor if you can pass it though the ant task)

So I think that you have to handle the target execution failure externally. To do so you can use  the [trycatch task from ant-contrib.](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

It will look like this:

```
<trycatch property="foo" reference="bar">
  <try>
    <record name="RunTest.log" action="start"/>
        <sf:compileAndTest  username="${sf.backup_username}" password="${sf.backup_password}" serverurl="${sf.backup_serverurl}" >
            <runTests Alltests="true"/>
        </sf:compileAndTest>
    <record name="RunTest.log" action="stop"/>
  </try>

  <catch>
    <echo>Got error while running compileAndTest</echo>
  </catch>

  <finally>
    <mail mailhost="email.corp.testcompany.com" mailport="25" subject="Run all tests - Sandbox 1337" messagefile="RunTest.log">
        <from address="user2@testcompany.com"/>
        <replyto address="user2@testcompany.com"/>
        <to address="user2@testcompany.com"/>
    </mail>
  </finally>
</trycatch>
```

Note that you can use the `<catch>`section to send special email when tests fail.

The `property` and `reference` can be use to get information about the failure (if any).

Comment: thanks for your reply I think my build failed thats why it doesnt go to email task is that right ?

Comment: @PrafullaPatil That's correct. This answer explains how to call the sendmail task, it does not solve the problem of sending a mail when the test fails

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look into the `failureProperty` and `haltOnFailure` attributes.

More info in this thread's answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/134563/708777